# PHP XPath : How to grab content AND html tags of a div?

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a webpage and I want to grab the text and all HTML tags inside a `div` tag.

The webpage looks like this:

```
<div class="class">
  <p>A little paragraph</p>
  <a href="#"><img src="/test.jpg"/></a>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using cURL I have succeeded in extracting all text but the tags are absent.

My  code:

```
$content = $xpath->query('//div[@class="class"]');
```

Comment: Which text do you want to extract?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy:

```
<?php

$html = '
<div class="class">
  <p>A little paragraph</p>
  <a href="#"><img src="/test.jpg"/></a>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$masterNode = $xpath->query('//div[@class="class"]'); #It returns DOMNodeList

# Now from master node we gonna pick what we want.
# Also, $masterNode->item(0) is context node for "P" tags.
$paragraphNodes = $xpath->query('p', $masterNode->item(0)); 

foreach ($paragraphNodes as $paragraphElement) {
    print $paragraphElement->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

The above code returns:

```
 A little paragraph
 Another paragraph
```

And here is a runnable sample: http://3v4l.org/9CYCs

## Grabing all childs nodes from div

```
<?php
// ...
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

Here is all child node from div.class (it returns a DOMNodeList instance):

```
$allChildNodesFromDiv = $xpath->query('//div[@class="class"]/*');
# Do somenthing with child nodes (see DOMElement)
foreach($allChildNodesFromDiv as $nodeElement) {
    # Do something with $nodeElement, for instance:
    print $nodeElement->nodeName;       
    print $nodeElement->nodeValue;  
   // ...   
}
```

Note [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php) is a set of [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domelement.php) objects.

**Related doc links:**

- [DOMXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domtext.php)
- [The DOMNodeList class](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php)
- [The DOMElement class](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domelement.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @felipsmartin.
But your solution return the same result that mine :/
I can't watch all HTML tags between my <div> tag.

Comment: And what you want grab, specifically?

Comment: Hello felipsmartins.
So, if I want to grab the entire div wich class name is "class".
I have to do a loop using condition like :

Comment: @Alex, yes! Because child nodes from DIV is a set of dom nodes (DOMElement) objects, so you must iterate over it.

Comment: Hello @felipsmartins
So, if I want to grab the entire div wich class name is "class".
I have to do another foreach ?
Like :
<kbd foreach ($nodeElement as $ne){
$xpath->query('//div[@class="class"]/'.$ne.');
#And here i can return or join data

Is it a good way to succed ?
Kind regards

Comment: @Alex, sorry, I have helped you a lot. Read the docs! All developers must read guides, it's elementary. I'm pretty sure that above snippet is much clear, even for a beginner PHP developer.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.
I will read the guides but I'm frustrated of my results :/
Even if I tried your way, I can't get HTML tags of the div, just the content :(

Answer (score 0):

For crawling i would recommend using php_query, below is the link. It provides jquery like selector to the pages. HTML pages are not necessary proper xml unless they are XHTML.

https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Comment: The latest version is from May 1, 2009. That was 6 years old when this answer was given. I highly recommend not using this. I used it 'till about 5 years ago when it got buggy

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
        $nodes = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' class')]");
        foreach($nodes as $full_name) {
            $class_full_content = trim($dom->saveHTML($full_name));
        }
```

Answer (score -4):

Use PHP to do it easily.

```
$all_data = file_get_contents("link of the url");
```

Now use: PHP regular expression, explode, implode etc to achieve your desired 
data.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: lol: You can easily do it. But you have to use: htmlentities($str) after that use regular expression and all filters. Finally use html_entity_decode . I think you will get seance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AdamSmith
So the easiest solution would be to explode the webpage using RegEx ?

I was using curl and Xpath like felipsmartins said